# why format specifier is getting inserted in the database? how to solve this?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

Below code will display the login page
when I enter the data from my login page it takes %s(format specifier) as input and stores it in database.
I think there is some problem with my insert query syntax .

Below is the code which I have tried.

```
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
my=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="kim",passwd="vats",port="3306",
auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',database="formm")
conn=my.cursor()

def login():
    Username=StringVar()
    password=StringVar()
    top=Toplevel()
    top.geometry('400x400')
    top.title("WELCOME")
    top.configure(bg='black')
    lable_0=Label(top, text="",bg='black').pack()
    lable_0=Label(top, text="",bg='black').pack()
    lable_0=Label(top, text="",bg='black').pack()

    label_e = Label(top, text="LOG IN",bg='black',fg='white',font=("bold", 20))
    label_e.pack()
    lable_0=Label(top, text="",bg='black').pack()

    label_1 = Label(top, text="Username",bg='black',fg='white',font=("bold", 14))
    label_1.pack()
    entry1=Entry(top,textvar=Username,bg='white')
    entry1.pack()
    lable_0=Label(root, text="",bg='black').pack()

    label_2 = Label(top, text="password",bg='black',fg='white',font=("bold", 14))
    label_2.pack()
    entry2=Entry(top,textvar=password,bg='white')
    entry2.pack()
    lable_0=Label(top, text="",bg='black').pack()

    Button(top, text='submit',width=20,bg='black',fg='white').pack()
    lable_0=Label(top, text="",bg='black').pack()


    add_employee = ("INSERT INTO login "
               "(Username, password) "
               "VALUES ('%s', '%s')")
    conn.execute(add_employee)
    my.commit()

root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("WELCOME")
root.configure(bg='black')
lable_4=Label(root, text="",bg='black').pack()
lable_4=Label(root, text="",bg='black').pack()
lable_4=Label(root, text="",bg='black').pack()
label_3 = Label(root, text="WELCOME",bg='black',fg='white',font=("bold", 20))
label_3.pack()

lable_4=Label(root, text="",bg='black').pack()

Button(root, text='Log In',width=20,bg='black',fg='white',command=login).pack()
lable_4=Label(root, text="",bg='black').pack()
Button(root, text='Sign Up',width=20,bg='black',fg='white').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The output should be the data what I enter in my GUI should get inserted into the database.
But the format specifier %s is getting inserted into my database which is wrong.

Comment: You're literally inserting `%s`. Why and what do you think something should get substituted for it?

Comment: I'm new to this so I need some help . I don't know the proper syntax of how to add the values from into my database using login gui . So if you know the answer please help

Answer (score 0):

You currently do this

```
add_employee = ("INSERT INTO login "
           "(Username, password) "
           "VALUES ('%s', '%s')")
conn.execute(add_employee)
```

In your execute command you just provide the query, you don't supply any values for it to insert in to the query.

Try something like

```
conn.execute(add_employee,(Username.get(),password.get())
```

This will pass a tuple containing the value of the username and password StringVar's to the query.

Note that with your current code, Username and password will be empty when you query is executed, you probably need to move it to a new function which is called when the submit button is pressed